# Find the proportion

Tags: probability, statistics, elementary-set-theory

80% of people like walking (Let this set be A)

60% of people like biking (Let this set be B)

100% like at least one of these

How many people like biking but not walking?

I need to find P(B\A).  I went about it this way:

P(B\A)=$P(B\cap A^c)$=P($A^c$) + P(B) - P($A^c \cup B$)

but P($A^c \cup B$)=P(B), so the answer is just P($A^c$).

Am I correct?

Comment: Why should $P(A^c\cup B)=P(B)$?

Comment: Hmm, ya I see the issue.  I don't know why I did that.  Have any ideas on the solution?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
$$
P(B)=P(B\cap A^c)+P(B\cap A).
$$

Comment: Yes, this helped a lot.  Thanks.